# how to get updated data from dyanamic generated edittext and put it in hashmap

Tags: android

I am creating a dyanamic layout having TextView and correspond Edittext. there is no problem to create it. I m using this :

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
tv = dynamicUiComponents.myTextView(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), 1000+i, key);
ed = dynamicUiComponents.myRowEditText(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT),50+i,value);
ed.setTag(key);

ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
{
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
update_columns.put(ed.getTag().toString(),s.toString());
}
});
}
```

The above statement is not able to identify updated edittext when I am using this:
update_columns.put(**ed.getTag().toString()**,s.toString());

The above bold statement always have the last added EditText tag value. Am i wrong anywhere?

Comment: No...The below line returns the last added edittext reference...  update_columns.put(ed.getText().toString(),s.toString());

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ed` is updated with every iteration of your while loop. It would be easier to keep a reference to the value of `ed.getTag().toString()` in the TextWatcher and reference that instead:

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
private String columnId = key; //Add this

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){ }

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {    }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  update_columns.put(this.columnId, s.toString());
}
});
```

This way each EditText's TextWatcher will update the corresponding column only.